# Hybrid MPI+OpenMP Vs MPI Performance

Tags: multithreading, mpi, openmp, shared-memory, pde

I am converting a 3-D Jacobi solver from pure MPI to Hybrid MPI+OpenMP. I have a `192x192x192` array which is divided among 24 processes in Pure MPI in `1-D` decomposition i.e. each process has `192/24 x 192 x 192 = 8 x 192 x 192` slab of data. Now I do :

```
for(i=0 ; i <= 7; i++)
  for(j=0; j<= 191; j++)
    for(k=0; k<= 191; k++)
     {
      unew[i][j][k] = 1/6.0 * (u[i+1][j][k]+u[i-1][j][k]+
                               u[i][j+1][k]+u[i][j-1][k]+
                               u[i][j][k+1]+u[i][j][k-1]);
     }
```

This update takes around 60 seconds for each process. 
Now with Hybrid MPI, I run two processes (1 process per socket `--bind-to socket --map-by socket` and `OMP_PROC_PLACES=cores`with `OMP_PROC_BIND=close`). I create 12 threads per MPI Process (i.e. 12 threads per socket or processor). Now each MPI process has an array of size : `192/2 x 192 x 192 = 96x192x192` elements. Each thread works on `96/12 x 192 x 192 = 8 x 192 x 192` *portion* of the array owned by each process. I do the same triple loop update using threads but the time is approximately 76 seconds for each thread. The load balance is perfect in both the problems. *What could be the possible causes of performance degradation ? Is is False Sharing because threads could be invalidating the cache lines close to each other's chunk of data ? If yes, then how do I reduce this performance degradation ?* (I have purposefully not mentioned ghost data but initially I am NOT overlapping communication with computation.)

In response to the comments below, am posting the code. Apologies for the long MWE but you can **very safely ignore** (1) Header files declaration (2) Variable Declaration (3) Memory allocation routine (4) Formation of Cartesian Topology (5) Setting boundary conditions in parallel using OpenMP parallel region (6) Declaration of `MPI_Type_subarray` datatype (7) `MPI_Isend()` and `MPI_Irecv()` calls and *just concentrate on* (a) `INDEPENDENT UPDATE` OpenMP parallel region (b) `independent_update(...)` routine being called from here.

```
/* IGNORE THIS PORTION */
#include<mpi.h>
#include<omp.h>


#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>


#define MIN(a,b) (a < b ? a : b)
#define Tol 0.00001

 /* IGNORE THIS ROUTINE */
void input(int *X, int *Y, int *Z)
{
    int a=193, b=193, c=193;
    *X = a;
    *Y = b;
    *Z = c;
}
 /* IGNORE THIS ROUTINE */
float*** allocate_mem(int X, int Y, int Z)
{
    int i,j;
    float ***matrix;
    float *arr;

    arr = (float*)calloc(X*Y*Z, sizeof(float));

    matrix = (float***)calloc(X, sizeof(float**));

    for(i = 0 ; i<= X-1; i++)
        matrix[i] = (float**)calloc(Y, sizeof(float*));

    for(i = 0 ; i <= X-1; i++)
        for(j=0; j<= Y-1; j++)
            matrix[i][j] = &(arr[i*Y*Z + j*Z]); 

    return matrix ; 
}

/* THIS ROUTINE IS IMPORTANT */

float independent_update(float ***old, float ***new, int NX, int NY, int NZ, int tID, int chunk)
{
    int i,j,k, start, end;
    float error = 0.0; 
    float diff;


        start = tID * chunk + 1;
        end = MIN( (tID+1)*chunk, NX-2 ); 

        for(i = start; i <= end ; i++)
        {
            for(j = 1; j<= NY-2; j++)
            {
                #pragma omp simd
                for(k = 1; k<= NZ-2; k++)
                {
                    new[i][j][k] = (1/6.0) *(old[i-1][j][k] + old[i+1][j][k] + old[i][j-1][k] + old[i][j+1][k] + old[i][j][k-1] + old[i][j][k+1] );
                    diff = 1.0 - new[i][j][k]; 
                    diff = (diff > 0 ? diff : -1.0 * diff ); 
                    if(diff > error)
                        error = diff;
                }
            }
        }   
    return error;  

}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    /* IGNORE VARIABLE DECLARATION */
    int size, rank;                         //Size of old_comm and rank of process
    int i, j, k,l;                          //General loop variables
    MPI_Comm old_comm, new_comm;            //MPI_COMM_WORLD handle and for MPI_Cart_create()
    int N[3];                               //For taking input of size of matrix from user
    int P;                                  //Represent number of processes i.e. same as size
    int dims[3];                            //For dimensions of Cartesian topology
    int PX, PY, PZ;                         //X dim, Y dim, Z dim of each process
    float ***old, ***new, ***temp;          //Matrices for results dimensions is (Px+2)*(PY+2)*(PZ+2)
    int period[3];                          //Periodicity for each dimension
    int reorder;                            //Whether processes should be reordered in new cartesian topology
    int ndims;                              //Number of dimensions (which is 3)
    int Z_TOWARDS_U, Z_AWAY_U;              //Z neighbour towards you and away from you (Z const)
    int X_DOWN, X_UP;                       //Below plane and above plane (X const)
    int Y_LEFT, Y_RIGHT;                    //Left plane and right plane (Y const)
    int coords[3];                          //Finding coordinates of processes
    int dimension;                          //Used in MPI_Cart_shift() , values = 0, 1,2 
    int displacement;                       //Used in MPI_Cart_shift(), values will be +1 to find immediate neighbours
    float l_max_err;                        //Local maximum error on process
    float l_max_err_new;                    //For dependent faces. 
    float G_max_err = 1.0;                  //Maximum error for stopping criterion
    int iterations = 0 ;                    //Counting number of iterations 
    MPI_Request send[6], recv[6];           //For MPI_Isend and MPI_Irecv               
    int start[3];                           //Start will be defined in MPI_Isend() and MPI_Irecv()
    int gsize[3];                           //Defining global size of subarray  
    MPI_Datatype x_subarray;                //For sending X_UP and X_DOWN
    int local_x[3];                         //Defining local plane size for X_UP/X_DOWN
    MPI_Datatype y_subarray;                //For sending Y_LEFT and Y_RIGHT
    int local_y[3];                         //Defining local plane for Y_LEFT/Y_RIGHT
    MPI_Datatype z_subarray;                //For sending Z_TOWARDS_U and Z_AWAY_U
    int local_z[3];                         //Defining local plan size for XY plane i.e. where Z=0

    double strt, end;                                   //For measuring time
    double strt1, end1, delta1;                         //For measuring trivial time 1
    double strt2, end2, delta2;                         //For measuring trivial time 2  
    double t_i_strt, t_i_end, t_i_sum=0;                            //Time for independent computational kernel
    double t_up_strt, t_up_end, t_up_sum=0;                         //Time for X_UP
    double t_down_strt, t_down_end, t_down_sum=0;                   //Time for X_DOWN
    double t_left_strt, t_left_end, t_left_sum=0;                   //Time for Y_LEFT
    double t_right_strt, t_right_end, t_right_sum=0;                //Time for Y_RIGHT
    double t_towards_strt, t_towards_end, t_towards_sum=0;          //For Z_TOWARDS_U   
    double t_away_strt, t_away_end, t_away_sum=0;                   //For Z_AWAY_U
    double t_comm_strt, t_comm_end, t_comm_sum=0;                   //Time comm + independent update (need to subtract to get comm time)
    double t_setup_strt,t_setup_end;                                //Set-up start and end time
    double t_allred_strt,t_allred_end,t_allred_total=0.0;           //Measuring Allreduce time separately.

    int threadID;                           //ID of a thread
    int nthreads;                           //Total threads in OpenMP region
    int chunk;                              //chunk - used to calculate iterations of a thread
    /* IGNORE MPI STARTUP ETC */
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    t_setup_strt = MPI_Wtime();

    old_comm = MPI_COMM_WORLD;
    MPI_Comm_size(old_comm, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(old_comm, &rank);
    P = size; 


    if(rank == 0)
    {
        input(&N[0], &N[1], &N[2]);
    }

    MPI_Bcast(N, 3, MPI_INT, 0, old_comm); 

    dims[0] = 0;
    dims[1] = 0;
    dims[2] = 0; 

    period[0] = period[1] = period[2] = 0;          //All dimensions aperiodic
    reorder = 0 ;                                   //No reordering of ranks in new_comm
    ndims = 3; 
    MPI_Dims_create(P,ndims,dims);
    MPI_Cart_create(old_comm, ndims, dims, period, reorder, &new_comm);



    if( (N[0]-1) % dims[0] == 0 && (N[1]-1) % dims[1] == 0 && (N[2]-1) % dims[2] == 0 )
    {

        PX = (N[0]-1)/dims[0];                      //Rows of unknowns each process gets
        PY = (N[1]-1)/dims[1];                      //Columns of unknowns each process gets
        PZ = (N[2]-1)/dims[2];                      //Depth of unknowns each process gets
    }


    old = allocate_mem(PX+2, PY+2, PZ+2);       //3D arrays with ghost points
    new = allocate_mem(PX+2, PY+2, PZ+2);       //3D arrays with ghost points


    dimension = 0; 
    displacement = 1; 

    MPI_Cart_shift(new_comm, dimension, displacement, &X_UP, &X_DOWN); //Find UP and DOWN neighbours

    dimension = 1; 
    MPI_Cart_shift(new_comm, dimension, displacement, &Y_LEFT, &Y_RIGHT); //Find UP and DOWN neighbours

    dimension = 2;
    MPI_Cart_shift(new_comm, dimension, displacement, &Z_TOWARDS_U, &Z_AWAY_U); //Find UP and DOWN neighbours



/* IGNORE BOUNDARY SETUPS FOR PDE */
#pragma omp parallel for default(none) shared(old,new,PX,PY,PZ) private(i,j,k) schedule(static)
    for(i = 0; i <= PX+1; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j <= PY+1; j++)
        {
            for(k = 0; k <= PZ+1; k++)
            {
                old[i][j][k] = 0.0;
                new[i][j][k] = 0.0; 
            }
        }
    }



#pragma omp parallel default(none) shared(X_DOWN,X_UP,Y_LEFT,Y_RIGHT,Z_TOWARDS_U,Z_AWAY_U,old,new,PX,PY,PZ) private(i,j,k,threadID,nthreads)
{   
    threadID = omp_get_thread_num();
    nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();

if(threadID == 0)
 {  
    if(X_DOWN == MPI_PROC_NULL)                         //X is constant here, this is YZ upper plane
    {
        for(j = 1 ; j<= PY ; j++)
            for(k = 1 ; k<= PZ ; k++)
            {
                old[0][j][k] = 1;
                new[0][j][k] = 1;                       //Set boundaries in new also
            }   
    }
}

if(threadID == (nthreads-1))
{
    if(X_UP == MPI_PROC_NULL)                           //YZ lower plane
    {
        for(j = 1 ; j<= PY ; j++)
            for(k = 1; k<= PZ ; k++)
            {
                old[PX+1][j][k] = 1;
                new[PX+1][j][k] = 1;
            }
    }
}


    if(Y_LEFT == MPI_PROC_NULL)                         //Y is constant, this is left XZ plane, possibly can use collapse(2) 
    {
    #pragma omp for schedule(static)
        for(i = 1 ; i<= PX ; i++)
            for(k = 1; k<= PZ; k++)
            {
                old[i][0][k] = 1;
                new[i][0][k] = 1; 
            }
    }

    if(Y_RIGHT == MPI_PROC_NULL)                        //XZ right plane, again collapse(2) potential 
    {
    #pragma omp for schedule(static)
        for(i = 1 ; i<= PX; i++)
            for(k = 1; k<= PZ ; k++)
            {
                old[i][PY+1][k] = 1;
                new[i][PY+1][k] = 1; 
            }   
    }

    if(Z_TOWARDS_U == MPI_PROC_NULL)                    //Z is constant here, towards you XY plane, collapse(2)
    {
     #pragma omp for schedule(static)
        for(i = 1 ; i<= PX ; i++)
            for(j = 1; j<= PY  ; j++)
            {
                old[i][j][0] = 1;
                new[i][j][0] = 1; 
            }
    }

    if(Z_AWAY_U == MPI_PROC_NULL)                       //Away from you XY plane, collapse(2) 
    {
    #pragma omp for schedule(static)
        for(i = 1 ; i<= PX; i++)
            for(j = 1; j<= PY ; j++)
            {
                old[i][j][PZ+1] = 1;
                new[i][j][PZ+1] = 1; 
            }   
    }

}

    /* IGNORE SUBARRAY DECLARATION */
    gsize[0] = PX+2;                    //Global sizes of 3-D cubes for each process
    gsize[1] = PY+2;
    gsize[2] = PZ+2;

    start[0] = 0;                       //Will specify starting location while sending/receiving 
    start[1] = 0;
    start[2] = 0;


    local_x[0] = 1;
    local_x[1] = PY;
    local_x[2] = PZ;

    MPI_Type_create_subarray(ndims, gsize, local_x, start, MPI_ORDER_C, MPI_FLOAT, &x_subarray);
    MPI_Type_commit(&x_subarray); 


    local_y[0] = PX;
    local_y[1] = 1;
    local_y[2] = PZ;

    MPI_Type_create_subarray(ndims, gsize, local_y, start, MPI_ORDER_C, MPI_FLOAT, &y_subarray);
    MPI_Type_commit(&y_subarray); 


    local_z[0] = PX;
    local_z[1] = PY;
    local_z[2] = 1;

    MPI_Type_create_subarray(ndims, gsize, local_z, start, MPI_ORDER_C, MPI_FLOAT, &z_subarray);
    MPI_Type_commit(&z_subarray); 

    t_setup_end = MPI_Wtime(); 

    strt = MPI_Wtime();

while(G_max_err > Tol) //iterations < ITERATIONS)
{

    iterations++ ; 


    t_comm_strt = MPI_Wtime();

        /* IGNORE MPI COMMUNICATION */
        MPI_Irecv(&old[0][1][1], 1, x_subarray, X_DOWN, 10, new_comm, &recv[0]);    
        MPI_Irecv(&old[PX+1][1][1], 1, x_subarray, X_UP, 20, new_comm, &recv[1]);
        MPI_Irecv(&old[1][PY+1][1], 1, y_subarray, Y_RIGHT, 30, new_comm, &recv[2]);
        MPI_Irecv(&old[1][0][1], 1, y_subarray, Y_LEFT, 40, new_comm, &recv[3]); 
        MPI_Irecv(&old[1][1][PZ+1], 1, z_subarray, Z_AWAY_U, 50, new_comm, &recv[4]);
        MPI_Irecv(&old[1][1][0], 1, z_subarray, Z_TOWARDS_U, 60, new_comm, &recv[5]);
        MPI_Isend(&old[PX][1][1], 1, x_subarray, X_UP, 10, new_comm, &send[0]);
        MPI_Isend(&old[1][1][1], 1, x_subarray, X_DOWN, 20, new_comm, &send[1]);
        MPI_Isend(&old[1][1][1], 1, y_subarray, Y_LEFT, 30, new_comm, &send[2]);
        MPI_Isend(&old[1][PY][1], 1, y_subarray, Y_RIGHT, 40, new_comm, &send[3]);
        MPI_Isend(&old[1][1][1], 1, z_subarray, Z_TOWARDS_U, 50, new_comm, &send[4]);
        MPI_Isend(&old[1][1][PZ], 1, z_subarray, Z_AWAY_U, 60, new_comm, &send[5]);
        MPI_Waitall(6, send, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);
        MPI_Waitall(6, recv, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);

    t_comm_end = MPI_Wtime();
    t_comm_sum = t_comm_sum + (t_comm_end - t_comm_strt); 



/* Use threads in Independent update */

    t_i_strt = MPI_Wtime();
    l_max_err = 0.0;                        //Very important, Reduction result is combined with this !

/* THIS IS THE IMPORTANT REGION */
    #pragma omp parallel default(none) shared(old,new,PX,PY,PZ,chunk) private(threadID,nthreads) reduction(max:l_max_err)
    {   
        nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
        threadID = omp_get_thread_num();

        chunk = (PX-1+1) / nthreads ; 

        l_max_err = independent_update(old, new, PX+2, PY+2, PZ+2, threadID, chunk); 

    }

    t_i_end = MPI_Wtime();
    t_i_sum = t_i_sum + (t_i_end - t_i_strt) ; 

    /* IGNORE THE REMAINING CODE */
    t_allred_strt = MPI_Wtime();
    MPI_Allreduce(&l_max_err, &G_max_err, 1, MPI_FLOAT, MPI_MAX, new_comm);
    t_allred_end = MPI_Wtime();
    t_allred_total = t_allred_total + (t_allred_end - t_allred_strt);


    temp = new ;
    new = old;
    old = temp;         
    }


    MPI_Barrier(new_comm);
    end = MPI_Wtime();

    if( rank == 0)
    {
        printf("\nIterations = %d, G_max_err = %f", iterations, G_max_err);
        printf("\nThe total SET-UP time for MPI and boundary conditions is %lf", (t_setup_end-t_setup_strt));
        printf("\nThe total time for SOLVING is %lf", (end-strt));
        printf("\nThe total time for INDEPENDENT COMPUTE %lf", t_i_sum);
        printf("\nThe total time for COMMUNICATION OVERHEAD is %lf", t_comm_sum);
        printf("\nThe total time for MPI_ALLREDUCE() is %lf", t_allred_total);
    }


    MPI_Type_free(&x_subarray);
    MPI_Type_free(&y_subarray);
    MPI_Type_free(&z_subarray);

    free(&old[0][0][0]);
    free(&new[0][0][0]); 

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;  

}
```

P.S. : I am almost sure that the cost of spawning/waking the threads is not the reason for such a huge difference in the timing. 
Please find attached Scalasca snapshot for INDEPENDENT COMPUTE of the Hybrid Program. 
[image: Thread execution for independent Compute in Hybrid Program]

Using loop simd construct

```
#pragma omp parallel default(none) shared(old,new,PX,PY,PZ,l_max_err) private(i,j,k,diff)
    { 
        #pragma omp for simd  schedule(static) reduction(max:l_max_err) 
        for(i = 1; i <= PX ; i++)
            {
                for(j = 1; j<= PY; j++)
                {
                    for(k = 1; k<= PZ; k++)
                    {
                        new[i][j][k] = (1/6.0) *(old[i-1][j][k] + old[i+1][j][k] + old[i][j-1][k] + old[i][j+1][k] + old[i][j][k-1] + old[i][j][k+1] );
                        diff = 1.0 - new[i][j][k]; 
                        diff = (diff > 0 ? diff : -1.0 * diff ); 
                        if(diff > l_max_err)
                            l_max_err = diff;
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: What happens if you run 24 threads in a single process (i.e. no MPI)?  How about 2 threads in each of 12 processes?

Comment: can you post the OpenMP version of your code ?

Comment: with 1 MPI task and 24 OpenMP threads, there will likely be a lot of NUMA effect that might severely impact performances. i'd rather compare pure MPI with 12 tasks on one socket vs one MPI tasks and 12 OpenMP threads on one socket.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet : I agree. That's the reason why I didn't compare the program with 1 MPI process and 24 threads with the pure MPI version. Trying to post the code...

Comment: @JohnZwinck: I think the most natural binding which automatically eliminates NUMA effects is binding one process each to a socket. My node has two sockets with 12 cores each. I am *just* concentrating on why a thread on the same sized chunk takes more time than an MPI process.

Comment: @GauravSaxena is 60 vs 76 seconds about `SOLVING` ? or just about `INDEPENDENT COMPUTE` (e.g. `t_i_sum`) ?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet: 60 Vs 76 seconds *just* about INDEPENDENT COMPUTE.

Comment: do you always use the same binary ? i do not see any difference in my box (dual socket 8 cores).(note i limited to 10000 iterations) flat : `OMP_NUM_THREADS=1 OMP_PROC_PLACES=core OMP_PROC_BIND=close mpirun --bind-to core -np 16 ./jacobi` : `The total time for INDEPENDENT COMPUTE 24.121219`. hybrid : `OMP_NUM_THREADS=8 OMP_PROC_PLACES=core OMP_PROC_BIND=close mpirun --map-by socket --bind-to socket -np 2 ./jacobi` : `The total time for INDEPENDENT COMPUTE 24.271490`

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet: My apologies ! I think when I just ran it right now it gave me equal timings. I must have compared two different decompositions :(. Many thanks for your help ! (I will delete the question in 10 minutes).

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet: I am also getting 80.49 (Pure MPI) Vs 80.46 (Hybrid). Thank you again for testing the code/timings....

Comment: What is the point on using OpenMP if then you manually divide the work among threads? Isn't it better to just add a `omp for` on the `independent_update` function? `for(i = start; i <= end ; i++)` would be `#pragma omp for schedule(static)` and `for( i = 1; i < NX-1; i++ )`. The advantage of OpenMP is that your code does not need to be aware that it is being executed by threads at all (in fact, it is not if you disable OpenMP at compile time).

Comment: @JorgeBellón: Thanks for pointing it out. I am using `#pragma omp simd` inside the `independent_update` function in the innermost loop. Is it possible to use this pragma with `#pragma omp for schedule(static)` ? (My current knowledge says it cant be used as the third loop becomes non-canonical).

Comment: It is totally possible: `#pragma omp for simd` is accepted, although in nested loops you usually want to distribute contiguous iterations to different simd lanes, meanwhile you want to distribute coarser iteration spaces among threads to maintain a good spatial locality.

Comment: @JorgeBellón: Thanks. I tried `#pragma omp for simd schedule(static)` and associated the triple nested loop with it. I get a time of `251.57` seconds as opposed to the original loop which gave `80.47` seconds. I think this loop simd construct is dividing the loop iteration into SIMD length chunks and giving it to the threads in a round-robin manner (not sure), so I still think that this loop simd construct cannot be used here. Please do correct me if I am wrong. Edited my answer to show added `loop simd` code.

Comment: Have you tried to use `#pragma omp for collapse(2)` at the outermost loop (`for( i = ... )`) and `#pragma omp simd` at the innermost (`for( k = ... )`)? SIMD is performs at its best when contiguous iterations access contiguous memory locations.

Comment: @JorgeBellón: Thanks. I tried it and it increases the time by around 1 second i.e. with collapse(2) clause `81.37` and without collapse clause `80.46`. I guess it must be the collapse overhead (not sure). But I certainly had misunderstood what OpenMP specifications meant by *canonical form* of the loop.

Comment: They mean that specifying loops other than the classic _for i = 1..10_ is not supported (it is necessary to deterministically know the number of iterations).

Answer (score 0):

You frequently get memory access and cache issues when you just do one MPI process per socket on a CPU with multiple memory controllers. It can be on either the read or the write side, so you can't really say which. This is especially an issue when doing thread-parallel execution with lightweight compute tasks (e.g. math on arrays). One MPI process per socket in this case tends to fare significantly worse than pure MPI.

1. In your BIOS, set up whatever the maximal NUMA per socket option is
2. Use one MPI process per NUMA node.
3. Try some different parameter values in schedule(static). I've rarely found the default to be best.

Essentially what this will do is ensure each bundle of threads only works on a single pool of memory.